# Backbone.js: calling render() from view's Initialize: function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to my view to render itself when it is first created, so I am calling `this.render();` in the `initialize:` function, like this (some code removed):

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#mydiv"),

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    }
...
```

In the `render:` function I'm then looping through a child collection, and appending the rendered views of each child element:

```
render: function() {
    this.model.somecollection.forEach(function(c) {
        var view = new ChildView({ model: c });
        this.el.append(view.render().el); //*****
    });
    return this;
},
```

The problem I'm having is that that the reference to `this` in the render function (marked with asterisks) is set to `window` rather than the `MyView` object, and it's causing an error.

I assume I am calling render incorrectly (currently `this.render();` ).  How should I be doing this so that the `this` context is preserved?

Comment: safe this as `that` outside the for loop.

Comment: @ZeissS - Doh! pretty dumb of me - add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save `this` outside the for loop.

```
var that = this;
```

`this` is not transported inside the loop if you use `_.each()`.

Comment: `Backbone.Collection.each()` takes a third argument for the context.

Comment: Cobby's comment is important. The `var that=this;` trick is a bit of a hack, and feels kind of crufty nowadays. Using a better `each` implementation reduces the noise a bit.

Comment: You can also use .bind() to set the this context.

Answer (score 5):

In Javascript, whenever you enter a new function context, the value of `this` has likely changed. All you need to do is store the value of `this` before you enter the function:

```
render: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.model.somecollection.forEach(function(c) {
        var view = new ChildView({ model: c });
        self.el.append(view.render().el); //*****
    });
    return this;
},
```

Answer (score 3):

this is how we use it here,

this way the render is still invoked when initialized.

```
ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        // we use underscsore templating, this just gives a chunk of html
        var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {} );
        // and we load that template html into the Backbone "el"
        this.el.html( template );
    }
});
```

we give the 'el' to the view when we create the view, 
and the render function inserts html into that element.

```
var contact_view = new ContactView({ el: $("#contact-list") });
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out it was a stupid mistake on my part (loosing this context because of the foreach/).each ).  But good to see an alternative approach.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of the anonymous function this refers to the global scope. You need to explicitly preserve this if you wish to use the code in the way you have written. Assuming you have jquery in your page : $.proxy function can be used : 

`this.model.somecollection.forEach($.proxy(function(c) {
        var view = new ChildView({ model: c });        
        this.el.append(view.render().el);
 },this));`

Alternatively, underscore has a _.bind function which works in a similar way. 
Also if you define a local variable and assign it to this outside the anonymous function, you can use that in place of this inside the anonymous function.

Answer (score 3):

If somecollection is a Backbone.Collection you should be able to say:

`this.model.somecollection.each(..., this);`

The last parameter is the context to be used inside the function.