# Trouble inserting to DOM child views in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

Trying to get my child views (OfferMarketView) created from the forEach back into the DOM. What is the best way to do this? I can't get the below working.

```
// DEFINE VIEW
var OfferView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.model = new Offers();
        this.model.fetch();
        this.model.on('change', this.modelChange);
        this.model.on('change', this.render);
        this.modelChange = function () {
            alert('model changed');
        };
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var container = this.el;
        this.model.forEach(function (s) {
            var view = new OfferMarketView({
                id: "container" + s.get('name').toLowerCase().replace(/\s*/g, '')
            });
            $("#offerCol").append(view.el);
        });
        return this;
    }
});
var OfferMarketView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    className: "classname",
    events: {},
    render: function() {
    }
});


// INITIALISE VIEW
offerView = new OfferView();
```

Comment: I don't know what you expect to obtain. I see that the `OfferMarketView.render` is empty and also is never called.. so `OfferMarketView.el` will be always `<div class="classname"></div>`. And then what you do is iterate over `this.model` that looks like a `Collection` and append your empty `<divs>` to an `#offerCol` element. Can you tell us what is exactly what do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

You have to render you view before appending the element:

```
$("#offerCol").append(view.render().el);
```

Note that you have to to add `return this;` in the render method so it is chainable:

```
var OfferMarketView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    className: "classname",
    events: {},
    render: function() {
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: I got an error in console, that OfferMarketView is not a constructor... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are not instanciating your OfferView before declaring the OfferMarketView view ?

Comment: I don't know why lots of tutorials use .append(view.el). Invoking render() is definitely the answer.